# How to update List Template

Tags: 2007, list-template

I have a list with several columns and different views.
I used a list template (.stp file) to create my list.

But in case of future updates or modifications, I want to be able to update my .stp file and add the new modifications to my list without deleting all my items or use the new updated template in an other site without erase all my list.

When I upload a document (.stp file) and overwrite an existing file, how does it work?

I'm using MOSS (SharePoint 2007)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way that when you update you can update your .stp file and reflect the changes on a created list. Once a list is created, that template is not already used for that list.

Given that data will be there, you better either do changes needed using manual steps or do using code.

Another option is creating a brand new list using the new list template and migrate data using a data migrate tool such as ShareGate. Which will be costly. Or you can use the datasheet view if available with SP 2007 lists.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to fix the list template and have it update the current lists based on it.

What you could do, is create content types with the desired list structure, and simply implement that content type on your lists. So when you update the content type, the new structure will be in your other lists as well.

Comment: The problem is that I used the same list template in 10 differents sites/web portals.
My modification is really basic/simple (just added a new view and a new column) which isn't that long to do manually. But I was just curious, for an eventual future major update.